# Can laravel include route not blade?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have blade file where i check user roles if user role admin show one content and if it's user show another content the problem is that i wanna include route for user not plain blade view without variables. Is there any way to do that?

My blade file:

```
@extends('admin/main') @section('content')

@if(Auth::user()->hasRoles('Darbuotojas'))
@include(route('darbuotojas.home')) // There i need to get route not view
@endif
@if(Auth::user()->hasRoles('Administratorius'))
<div class="container dydis">
  <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center text-center">
    <div class="col-md-10" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="400">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8 text-center">
          <h4>Darbuotojai</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>    
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div style="position: relative; top: 50px; left: 15px; z-index: 1000">
        Rodyti/Slėpti:
        <a class="toggle-vis btn-sm btn-primary" href="#" data-column="0"
          >Barkodas</a
        >
        <a href="#" class="toggle-vis btn-sm btn-primary" data-column="1"
          >Tabelio nr.</a
        >
        <a href="#" class="toggle-vis btn-sm btn-primary" data-column="2"
          >Vardas</a
        >
        <a href="#" class="toggle-vis btn-sm btn-primary" data-column="3"
          >Pavardė</a
        >
        <a href="#" class="toggle-vis btn-sm btn-primary" data-column="4"
          >Įmonė</a
        >
        <a href="#" class="toggle-vis btn-sm btn-primary" data-column="5"
          >Miestas</a
        >
        <!--<a href="#" class="toggle-vis btn-sm btn-primary" data-column="6">Vadovas</a> pakeisti data column -->
        <a href="#" class="toggle-vis btn-sm btn-primary" data-column="6"
          >Padalinys</a
        >
        <a href="#" class="toggle-vis btn-sm btn-primary" data-column="7"
          >Pareigos</a
        >
        <a href="#" class="toggle-vis btn-sm btn-primary" data-column="8"
          >Telefonas</a
        >
        <a href="#" class="toggle-vis btn-sm btn-primary" data-column="9"
          >El. paštas</a
        >
        <a href="#" class="toggle-vis btn-sm btn-primary" data-column="10"
          >Veiksmai</a
        >
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
@endif
@stop
```

Comment: What do you mean "you want to include the route"? You want `/home` to show up there?

Comment: `@include(route('darbuotojas.home'))` to `<a href="{{route('darbuotojas.home') }}"> Home</a>`

Comment: @kerbh0lz correct i wanna show whole route not only blade

Comment: You should refactor your code so you can include a blade common blade that both users and admins will see. It's bad practice to try to include the result of a route in a blade

Answer (score 1):

use `{{ route('darbuotojas.home') }}` instead of `@include(route('darbuotojas.home'))`

Also if you want to include the blade do not including it by its route, include it using its path. `@include('path/to/home.blade.php')`

Comment: first part doesn't work. I don't need second part include blade works for me.